# Initializing table name to be used in a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a stored procedure to achieve the following in the stored procedure

```
DECLARE @TBLNAME VARCHAR(128)

SET @TBLNAME = SELECT PAR_VALUE FROM DBO.PARAMETERS WHERE PAR_NAME='SALES_ORDERS_TABLE';
```

The `PAR_VALUE` column in the `PARAMETERS` table contains the name of the table of the `Sales Order` table.

I now want to use this table name in the stored procedure, and count the number of rows in this table.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
@ SQL = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '[@TBLNAME]'
```

However, when I try to run this, there are multiple errors.

Can you please help me by guiding on how to do this?

I just now tried this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE JCOUNT_SO
AS
DECLARE @TBLNAME NVARCHAR(512)
SELECT @TBLNAME=(SELECT PAR_VALUE FROM DBO.PARAMETERS WHERE PAR_NAME='SALES_ORDERS_TABLE')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @SQL='SELECT COUNT(*) AS #_OF_RECORDS INTO SO_COUNT
FROM' '+QUOTENAME(@TBLNAME)''

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

**Error Message: Invalid Object Name: 'TEST.DBO.SO_MASTER'**

Please help on this code.

Comment: SQL expects to encounter a *name*, not a *string* in the `FROM` clause. There are some ugly workarounds, but trying to treat the table parametrically is usually a sign of issues with the schema (e.g. having multiple tables with the exact same structure, rather than a single table with additional column(s))

Comment: Hi Damien, I understand your point about issues with schema. However, in this case, I need to go ahead with this approach. Can you please share the workarounds you mentioned above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read defination of [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for reference. Procedure below returns value as an output parameter from dynamic query rather than inserting into a table. You can manipulate query as per your requirement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE JCOUNT_SO
    AS

    DECLARE @TBLNAME nvarchar(512)

    --Obtain table name. Top 1 is used to pick first record rather than last record in case query returns more than one record.

    SELECT TOP 1 @TBLNAME = PAR_VALUE FROM DBO.PARAMETERS WHERE PAR_NAME='SALES_ORDERS_TABLE'

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @Count int 
    SET @SQL ='SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TBLNAME

    --Define parameters to be passed i.e. @Count is being passed as output parameter
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@Count int OUTPUT', @Count output
    select @Count

    end
```

**Notes from MSDN**

Query i.e. `@SQL` can contain parameters having the same form as a variable name and each parameter included in `@SQ`Lmust have a corresponding entry in both the `@params` parameter definition list and the `parameter values` list

Answer (score 0):

1 point I can say is ... it should be `SET @SQL = SELECT ...` 
and one more thing is you can try converting the result to `NVARCHAR`.

use `SELECT Convert(NVARCHAR(4000),Count(*)) FROM ...`

Comment: can you pls give the full syntax? Thanks!